# How can I handle OnSuspending with WinUI 3

Tags: c#, winui-3

This time I must migrate an UWP App to WinUI 3, so far everything has worked well except for a few small things but the event `OnSuspending` is simply not triggered. In the namespace Windows.UI.Xaml you could easily use

```
this.Suspending += OnSuspending
```

in app.xaml.cs and it wasn't a problem, in Microsoft.UI.Xaml I can't do this. I have now declared a `SuspendingEventhandler` in app.xaml.cs

```
public event SuspendingEventHandler Suspending;
```

but this just doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using the experimental UWP app model in your WinUI 3 app? Because desktop apps are not suspended.

Comment: In the UWP Application, that I must be migrate, the OnSuspending event get triggerd if the Application get Closed, at this moment the App settings and data get saved. Now i saved this on another way and removed the Suspending event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WinUI **3** can be used to build *desktop/WIn32* Windows apps (see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077)) and this kind of apps are [not suspended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.suspendingeventhandler?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) so there is no `Suspending` event ever being raised.

Comment: Thx, this is the first time that I work with an UWP and an WinUI 3 Application, there are many things to learn for me.